# Как клонировать виртуальную машину?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu

Есть новый настроенный образ для VirtualBox. Как создать точно такую же копию (речь не о снимках, а именно о второй машине).

Answer (score 3):

Скопируйте том, создайте новую ОС и при выборе хранилища не создавайте новое хранилище, а выберите копию тома.

Answer (score 2):

Поставьте свежую версию. Там прямо в ней появился значок с овцой. Этим можно клонировать машину (без снимков естественно).

Comment: кстати есть еще один выход, есть утилита меняющая ключ диска, столкнулся недавно с этой проблемой (снимков на машине не было, просто 2 идентичные нужны были), после копирования меняет id, вроде бы в винде она родная, в сети есть инфо об этом, про линукс не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

А если документацию почитать? [vboxmanage clonevm](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevm)

Answer (score 2):

Лично мне надо было сделать две виртуальные машины(одинаковые) на двух компьютерах.Я просто установил и настроил все на первом компьютере,а потом на другом установил программу и скопировал с первой виртуальный диск системы(*.vdi) на второю и просто указал при создании новой машины "использовать существующий диск"