# Резервная копия VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Мне необходимо бэкапить виртуалку и хранить копии на другом компе, на случай если первый комп сгорит.

Не могу понять что мне нужно хранить? Какие файлы, что бы я потом смог восстановить последнее стояние виртуалки и все ее данные?

Допустим если один раз экспортировать виртуалку, а затем копировать ее снимки(каждый день), то я смогу потом по этому экспорту и снимкам восстановить данные и последнее состояние?

Comment: Близко к дубликату: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/992728/262779

Comment: ещё дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/338826/178576